How to control sequence of execution of customtkinter program
The attached customtkinter program jumps to the end print statements before any selection from the comboboxes. How can I control the program execution so the user selects the baudrate and port from the comboboxes and then the tk.IntVar and tk.String.Var are updated to be used in another section of the program that will connect to a serial port with the baudrate and port tk.variables
also how do I get the 4 space indent on the code below so others won't need to correct it thanks
type here#
#
import os
import os.path
import sys
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ast import literal_eval
from tkinter import *
# from tkinter import CENTER, constants
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
import threading
import customtkinter 
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import tkinter
import glob

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")
#lock = threading.Lock()


def baud_rate():
    #global b_rates
    b_rates = ("9600", "19200", "38400", "57600", "115200")
    #print('baud rate list is ',b_rates)
    return b_rates

def serial_ports():
    """ thanks to the original function writer don't remember
        where it's from many months ago
    """
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
        # this excludes your current terminal "/dev/tty"
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')

    result = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass
    return result

def update_baud():
    while baud_set == None:
        baud_val_set = baud_combobox.get()
        baud_set.set(baud_val_set)
        print('baud_set = ',baud_set)
        
def update_port():
    while port_set == None:
        port_val_set = port_combobox.get()
        port_set.set(port_val_set)
        print('port_set = ',port_set)
    
  
app = customtkinter.CTk()

port_str_in = tk.StringVar()
port_str_in = serial_ports()

baud_str_in = tk.StringVar()
baud_str_in = baud_rate()

baud_set = tk.IntVar(app)
port_set = tk.StringVar(app)

def port_sel(*args):
    global port_set
    port_sel_val = port_combobox.get()
    port_set = port_sel_val
    print('Port value is ',port_combobox.get())
    #print(port_set)
    #return  port_sel_val
    return  port_set 
 
def baud_sel(*args):
    global baud_set
    baud_set = 0
    baud_sel_val = baud_combobox.get()
    s_sel_baud = int(baud_sel_val)
    baud_set = s_sel_baud
    print('Int value of baudrate is ',baud_combobox.get())
    #print(baud_set)
    #return s_sel_baud
    return  baud_set

update_baud()
update_port()

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app,
                               width=350,
                               height=350,
                               corner_radius=10)
frame.pack(padx=20, pady=10)

baud_combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=frame,
                                          values=(baud_str_in),
                                          command=baud_sel)

baud_combobox.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)

port_combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=frame,
                                          values=(port_str_in),
                                          command=port_sel)

port_combobox.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.4, anchor=CENTER)



baud = update_baud()
com = update_port()

print('baud value ',baud)
print('com value ',com)


app.mainloop()



Tried threads, threads with locking, multi-threading. I could have done those wrong. I was expecting a String variable for the port and a int variable for the baudrate to be passed to a serial port connect function.
